Increasing file weight joining mesh
I'm using Blender to join into a unique mesh an industral machine (.FBX file), that it's made of thounsands of mesh, but when i do it the file weight increase from 60Mb to 250Mb. I've read that could be the UV Maps but i haven't them in my file, I've purge unused data yep, but it doesn't change. Could someone help me? It's for a scientist research, to trasform STEP file into IFC

The same thinks happends when i use a code to rename all the meshes in the file, I've wrote this code because different objects in the file had the same mesh

If you want an IFC file from a STEP why go through FBX in the middle? It will lose all solid geometry, and you will end up with lots of triangulated meshes

Because Blender doesn’t open a .STP file

Blender seems like the wrong tool for the job then. Why not FreeCAD which opens both, or any other CAD package if you aren't bound to free options. I think I've even seen simple converter scripts online, that do so directly. Either way, thousands of objects are bound to make a large file size, regardless of storage format

If different objects used the same mesh as instances, there is a great reduction of weight because the mesh is stored once, then instanced many times, while the procedure of joining or renaming can make instances real meshes, increasing the amount of data to be stored.
Objects can be seen as "containers", that host an Object Data datablock, which is responisble of holding all informations about vertices, edges, faces, attributes, ....
In my simple example the default cube has been duplicated using Alt D, so that the two containers (objects) share the same Object Data datablock (named object data cube).
Selecting all and going in edit mode you can read that the scene is composed by 8 vertices.
When joining the two containers the Object data is responsible to hold all necessary geometry, so it counts 16 vertices.



Yes I know, but I don’t understand why if I join all in one, the weight increase

I updated my answer.

Ok, you are right. Do you know any solutions how to keep the icreasing weight, low? Because when i export as IFc file, that IFC is for me too heavy to use.
